# Cesium: format of tiles and format of maps relation

Tags: google-maps, gis, gdal, cesiumjs, mbtiles

I'm using Cesium based applicaton to view my orthomaps on earth maps.

For now as I'm using [Cesium.createTileMapServiceImageryProvider](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/createTileMapServiceImageryProvider.html) as tiles provider and `gdal2tiles` as tiler which use TMS tile format, as 'earth maps' I use [Cesium.ArcGisMapServerImageryProvider](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/ArcGisMapServerImageryProvider.html).

So my questions are:

1. Does earth maps imagery provider depends on tiles format?
2. What if I want to switch to Google tiles format, which tiler should I use? do I restricted to use Google Maps as 'earth maps'?
3. Why I should prefer one tile format to another (for example mbtiles), which tile format have the fastest tiler?